# Can the Map function of Map Reduce call a (external) web service?

Tags: web-services, mapreduce

I have to write a Map Reduce job in Java which use an external web service. my questions is whether it is allowed to invoke an HTTP request from the Map function of a Map Reduce job, i.e:

```
public class GeoLocator {

private static String genderCheck = "female";    

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper {
    /* CALL EXTERNAL WEB SERVICE HERE */
    }
    .. 
}
```

If so, how can I invoke the web service?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the old API, since, I see this line in your class,

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper {}
```

So, with respect to that, first, you need to set the webservice URL in your JobConf object, later, from the JobConf instance retrieve the same url in the mapper.

Furthermore, make sure your webservice url is accessible from all the Hadoop nodes

For e.g-

In main() function, you can do something like,

```
JobConf job = (JobConf) getConf();
job.set("webservice.url", "http://your_address_whatsoever");
```

And in the Mapper class -

```
String url = null;
public void configure(JobConf job) {
       url = (String) job.get("webservice.url");
}
```

But I suggest you use the new API to kind of make things easy -

in main() you can simply go ,

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
set("webservice.url", "http://your_address_whatsoever");
```

And the mapper class's map() function simply do

```
String url = context.getConfiguration().get("webservice.url");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!  I invoke the web service through codes like below in the Map() function, serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient(); Options options = serviceClient.getOptions(); EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(endpoint); options.setTo(targetEPR); QName opQName = new QName(namespaceURI, optionName);  System.out.println(serviceClient.invokeBlocking(opQName, opArgs, opReturnType));  is there someting wrong? should I write the invoking in the Map() function?

Comment: I'm sorry about the layout of my comment! I encounter something wrong!

Comment: In the configure() function, you can do all the initialization stuffs you have mentioned and if you want you can invoke the webservice in the map() function.
The sample code I have provided just shows you how you can pass configurations (e.g. service urls) to different mappers running throughout the cluster. Obviously, you can hard code the url in the map function but, I feel it's not a good idea.

Comment: So your advice is I'd better do the preparation for invoking in the configure()function,and just pass configurations to map()function, am I right?

Comment: That's fine- invoke the webservice if required inside map() and do the initialization stuff in the configure(). BTW, configure() is supposed to be a overridden function from Mapper Class you are extending.

Comment: I encounter another problem, how to pass the splits to web service? The web service invoking seems like apart from the data.

Comment: Hi Cherry, by splits, do you mean the records/values you read in the map function?